# WPF DataGridTemplateColumn Combobox Issues

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I'm having some issues exactly figuring out how to go about doing this. I basically want to have a ComboBox in a DataGrid (using DataGridTemplateColumn with ComboBoxItems currently) that I am able to select from static options. What I also need is when I select an option from the combobox and finish editing the row for the data/inputs to be sent to my SQL database table (**STATUS**). I have that working for a DataGridTextColumn, but not this ComboBox type.

In this STATUS table there are four columns, two TextColumns and two ComboBoxColumns. I have gotten other tables to work perfectly fine with ItemsSource and Bindings. Not sure how to do this with ComboBox columns.

When I load this DataGrid a filter applies (via SQL query) to only show specific rows for specific times. I need to be able to have the SQL DB also show the correct data for previous entries.

**XAML:**

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="STATUS" Width="512.5">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox Text="{Binding STATUS}" SelectedValue="{Binding STATUS, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="GREEN" Tag="0"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="YELLOW" Tag="1"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="ORANGE" Tag="2"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="RED" Tag="3"/>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

*I know the Text Binding is probably incorrect. It seems every time I load the DataGrid with this configuration the rows duplicate the same data.*

**C#:**

```
private static string GDC_ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GDC_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
private static string CmdString;
private static SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GDC_ConnectionString);
private static SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);
private static SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
private static DataTable dtPTR_STATUS = new DataTable("ptrSTATUS");

private void ptrSTATUS_GRID_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //ApplyPTR_StatusFilter();
    CmdString = "SELECT * FROM STATUS WHERE CONVERT(date,DATE_STATUS,101) = CONVERT(date,GETDATE(),101)";
    cmd.CommandText = CmdString;
    sda.Fill(dtPTR_STATUS);
    ptrSTATUS_GRID.ItemsSource = dtPTR_STATUS.DefaultView;
}

private void ptrSTATUS_GRID_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GDC_ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
        builder.GetInsertCommand();
        builder.GetUpdateCommand();
        sda.Update(dtPTR_STATUS);
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

[Here's an image as an example of what I'm trying to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpmVd.png)

Basically the SQL DB/query shows any appropriate rows via the filter (and will allow edits via the SqlBuilder GetUpdate command). Then a new row is displayed with static options and when the row edit ends send that data to the SQL database (which in turn will display when re-loaded due to the SQL query/filter). Is this actually possible with a ComboBox? I've got it working flawlessly with regular TextBoxColumns.

Any help would be appreciated! Apologies for anything wrong on my part as I'm new here and to WPF/C# overall.

Comment: how the status are stored in the table, via a status code (0 => green, ...) or just as the string value ?

Comment: It's a string value. The 'tag' value in the XAML code was my attempt of trying to figure out various solutions. In the SQL database/table it's just a varchar(50) column.

Answer (score 0):

The edit is just ending when you call your update method so the new value has not already been saved for the update.

You should call the `EndEdit()` method before the update.

```
    private void ptrSTATUS_GRID_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
        {
            DataRowView rowView = e.Row.DataContext as DataRowView;
            rowView?.Row.EndEdit();
        }

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GDC_ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);

            sda.Update(dtPTR_STATUS);
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

I have updated the XAML code also:

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" MinWidth="512.5">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding STATUS}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding STATUS, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  SelectedValuePath="Tag">
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="GREEN" Tag="GREEN"/>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="YELLOW" Tag="YELLOW"/>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="ORANGE" Tag="ORANGE"/>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="RED" Tag="RED"/>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: But what if I am trying to **add** a row into the database? How would adding CommitEdit() change anything? The TextBoxColumns work fine without this, so I'm unsure how to go about actually getting my ComboBox columns so *save* the data I enter. EDIT: I tried your solution and it didn't change any of the issues I was having so I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: CommitEdit will validate the input data as new value for the row. And when the update will be applied, the new values will be taken. I have edited the code. The two removed lines  should remove the problem with the duplicate rows

Comment: So the code somewhat works, but there's still some odd issues I'm having. In this image I had the appropriate previous record showing. https://i.imgur.com/KYYlMJ2.png The issue is when I add a new row (using the 'CanUserAddRows' feature) it adds the **Tag** number rather than the content. Additionally, the previous rows keep duplicating in view, which I'm not sure why. Any further suggestions? I appreciate the help! This is definitely farther than I've gotten..